# Appending html elements to a table

Tags: jquery, html-table

Two of the "things" I display should be next to each other, that's why I want to go for this code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Where I'm stuck is how to implement this with appending, so far I have this, but it isn't working:

```
tddiv = $("<td/>")
    .appendTo(trdiv);

trdiv = $("<tr/>")
    .appendTo(tablediv);

tablediv = $("<table/>")
    .appendTo(contentdiv);

contentdiv = $("<div/>") 
    .attr("data-role", "content") 
    .appendTo(pagediv);

$("<img/>")
    .addClass("artistimg")
    .attr("src", "http://images.q-music.be/" + oTrack.artist.photo)
    .appendTo(tddiv);

$("<h2/>")
    .text(oTrack.artist.name)
    .appendTo(tddiv);
```

Comment: I dont think there is such tag in html "<td/>" dont you?

Comment: @niko jquery parse it

Comment: Oh i did not know that :) that is the reason i visit stack overflow it teaches me a variety ways of coding :)

Comment: @niko That's a valid way to create a collection containing a DOM element. `$('<tr/>')` == a collection containing 1 `<tr></tr>`

Comment: Your logic should be to add to table a TR with TD and then add TABLE to container DIV

Comment: your first var references trdiv var btu this is created after the first thus doe not know what trdiv is? perhaps this could be the issue

Comment: Firstly you are attempting to append the `td` to the `tr` before the `tr` exists yet. Similarly with the `tr` and the `table`. Also, instead of using a table, try two `div` elements set to `float: left` or `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to append each element to its parent before creating them. In the following example:

```
tddiv = $("<td/>")
    .appendTo(trdiv);

trdiv = $("<tr/>")
    .appendTo(tablediv);
```

`trdiv` is first mentioned on line 2, but it's only created on line 4. A much simpler (and computationally cheaper) way of doing this would be to simply write the whole thing out as one HTML string:

```
var contentdiv = $( '\
<div data-role="content">\
  <table>\
    <tbody>\
      <tr>\
        <td>\
          <img class="artistimg" src="http://images.q-music.be/' + oTrack.artist.photo +  '">\
          <h2>' + oTrack.artist.name + '</h2>\
');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `trdiv`, `contentdiv` and `tablediv` do not exist when you're trying to append to it. Also, you'll need to wrap your code inside the DOMReady function (`$(function() {  });` for example, or `$(document).ready(function() {  });`):

```
contentdiv = $('<div/>').data('role', 'content').appendTo(pagediv);
tablediv = $('<table/>').appendTo(contentdiv);
trdiv = $('<tr/>').appendTo(tablediv);
tddiv = $('<td/>').appendTo(trdiv);


$('<img/>').addClass('artistimg').prop('src', 'http://images.q-music.be/' + oTrack.artist.photo).appendTo(tddiv);

$('<h2/>').text(oTrack.artist.name).appendTo(tddiv);
```

Also note the use of [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) and [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to replace `attr('data-*')` and [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

If the only reason to use `<table>` elements here is for styling, **don't**! It's 2014 now, so you should be using CSS to achieve this. Tables should be used to present tabled data, not to style information in two columns. You can easily achieve what you're trying to do with some simple markup and CSS as follows:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell fifty"></div>
    <div class="cell fifty"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.row {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

    .row .cell {
        float: left;
        padding: 10px;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
           -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
    }
        .cell.fifty {
             width: 50%;
        }
```

[<kbd>**jsFiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/Wr4Fn/1/)